# CSS shrink container to size of two dynamic width divs

Tags: html, css

This is what I'm trying to achieve

```
                            CONTAINER
 --------------------------------------------------------------
|                      CENTERED in CONTAINER                   |
|    -----------------------------------------   ----------    |
|   | Content Div                             | | Info Div |   |
|   | shrink to contents  OR                  | | shrink to|   |
|   | max size: (container width - info div ) | | contents |   |
|   |                                         |  ----------    |
|    -----------------------------------------                 |
|                                                              |
|    ------------------------------------------------------    |
|   |  text div: width = width of content div + info div   |   |
|    ------------------------------------------------------    |
 --------------------------------------------------------------
```

PICTURES (crude MSPAINT): [small content example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yCFL5.png) and [large content example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/byhVI.png)

DIV INFO: Max 192 pixels, but should shrink if necessary.

DIV CONTENT: Shrink to content. If content is large, width= remaining space in container.

DIV TEXT: width = width of CONTENT + width of INFO.

Here's what I have so far. I am not using floats because I want the content and info divs to be overall centered on the page.

The problems I am having are:

- the text div expands to the container size.
- if the browser window is shrunk, the info div gets bumped to the next
  line.

### CSS

```
#container {
    width: 80%;
    min-width: 760px;
    padding-top: 0;
    margin: 0 auto; 
}
#content {
    max-width: 71%; /* Kinda solves the problem of bumping info div
                       to next line, but leave awkward gaps */
    width: auto;
    vertical-align: top;
    display: inline-block;
}
#info {
    width: auto;
    vertical-align: top;
    text-align: left;
    display: inline-block;
}
#text {
    margin: 10px auto;
    width: auto;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
}
```

### HTML

```
<div id="container">
<div id="main">
    <div id="content"><img src="image.jpg" />Lorem ipsum ...</div>
    <div id="info">Lorem ipsum dolor</div>
    <div id="text">Lorem ipsum ...</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: ASCII art wireframes make me smile.

Comment: I guess I could dynamically resize in Javascript, but I'm wondering if there is an elegant CSS solution.

Comment: Just quick suggestion: have you noticed that you have <div class="container"> and you apply css with: #container, although you should use .container?

Comment: @user194076: T_T, just spent 10 minutes finding that bug

Comment: Is it possible to accept two answers? Shaz and Myles Gray each provided a part of the complete solution. Thanks to both of you!

Answer (score 5):

Try this: <s>http://jsfiddle.net/JbuBC/2/</s>
http://jsfiddle.net/JbuBC/14/

Comment: Hmm, no comment. What's wrong with the template I gave? Let me know and I'll try to fix it. :)

Comment: Sorry, got lost playing around with the CSS. I do appreciate the help! Basically the issue I have with giving a width %, is that the DIV INFO is not the smallest width it should be. Then DIV CONTENT should also be the smallest possible, up to the remainder of available width in the container. But once you start removing width %, then the DIV TEXT always takes 100% of the container

Comment: Okay so you want the "container" to stay the same size but the "incontainer" to change size depending on the contents of "info" and "text"; and have "info", "text", and "content" to take up as little space as possible?

Comment: Almost, "container" is always 80% width (with minimum of 760px). "incontainer" shrinks to size of "content"+"info". "content" and "info" are respectively small as possible. "text" is width of "content"+"info"= width of "incontainer". Does this make sense?

Comment: I think this is it. Back to tables it is, just gotta check really  large content does not over flow.

Comment: Yeah, you rarely see me use tables, or even style attributes (such as width, align, etc...) on html elements, but it's the only way I could get it working for now. :/

Comment: As suggested by as Myles Gray. had to use a javascript  to set the container width if the content was very large to keep from bumping DIV INFO to the next line

Comment: @Shaz: I believe this is the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/JbuBC/102/ When there is a bunch of text, the whole thing gets strange. I'd want the text to wrap at the shrink-wrapped size.

Answer (score 3):

Add `float:left;` to `#info` and `#content`

Remove `max-width: 71%;` from `#content`

HTML code would be a good help if you have some?

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mutant_Tractor/q4dEG/3/)**

Comment: I appreciate the help. Added some HTML and picture examples to the question and tried to clarify my goals.

Comment: If you stretch the window out -- i.e. have a large resolution -- you get an increasing gap between the DIV CONTENT and DIV INFO.

Comment: There is still a gap if the width of DIV text is smaller than 192px. Thanks for the help but I think the tables solution that Shaz posted is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

To make #text width equals to Content+Info width you need to wrap #content, #info, #text with one more div.

Comment: Tried that, #text width is still width of the container. Adding display: inline-block; fixes that but then moves everything to the left of the container and results in weird issues of going outside the container if the width is large